# Convert Tris to Quads or Polygons

Tags: unity, 3d, mesh

Im working on a ledge climbing system in Unity. I am coding a method that takes a mesh and tries to generate a bunch of connected nodes that will help the player detect ledges that can be climbed.

This is what I have made so far:
[image]

The thing I need to do now is to remove connections that are not ledges (sorry if that doesn't explain much). This is the desired result:
[image]

So, basically, I need to convert those Tris to Polygons. I have no idea of how to do this. Each node stores its position, its normal, and what nodes it is connected to.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What I would try is for each edge, get the two joined faces, get those faces' normals and calculate the angle between the two faces using a dot product.

Comment: @RyanSpeets That sounds like the seed of a good answer, if you'd like to expand on how you'd accomplish this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem is pretty much solved by you having carefully crafted the nodes yourself, I'm just going to offer up a method to remove the interconnections.

Your each node has two or more connections, but a node at the "edge" of your mesh will only ever have two connections. These will always be towards the "outside" of your mesh, meaning your edges will trace the mesh from the outside.

So, what you need to do is to take the first node you can find with two connections and start there. Lets say you have a mesh like so:
[image]

What you want is to have connections between the outer nodes and remove all else. Now, you go over the nodes and find the first one with two connections. Let's say you've found D in this example. Next, you need to move on to another node which is connected to D. Since E has too many connections to think about and since it's actually easier to solve compared to the others (I'll explain this later), I'm going to go with A.

So, we're on the node A and we have three nodes connected to A. We only need two, so we need to eliminate one. The way we go about that is to find the previous connection we came from (which is D in this case) and then go over each of the connections and find which one has the largest angle value between the previous connection (A-D) and the current one. In this case, this would be A-B connection with a 90 degree angle difference (since A-E to A-D has a 45 degree difference). So, we need the A-B connection to stay, then we let the A-E connection go. Now we have this:
[image]

Before we move on, I'd like to add something. In case you have a larger angle than 180 like a 230 or something, you need to find where your object is then decide whether this angle is actually 230 or just 130. If your angle is not facing your object then you need to find the one that is facing your object (i.e. do a subtraction from 360). This could be a question in and of itself, so I'm not going to go into too much detail on this.

Next up, we move onto B (since we came from D and the only other connection A is now B). Now we look at each connection B has and find out that B is connected to A and C which are both outer nodes (they only have two connections), so B must also be an outer node. We pick B-C to stay and remove B-E and B-F. Then we move on to C, and see that it only has two connections, so we move on to F. Since F has three connections (and only one is an outer node, which is C), we look at each connection and compare angles and decide that E-F has to go. Then we do the same with H (in which case it's already connected to two outer nodes) and remove E-H. Then we move on to G, then E then when we come back to D, our starting node, we stop and have a perfect edge detection (in theory).

[image]

You might be thinking, "Why didn't we go to E node instead at first? Is that because E has too many connections?", and the answer would be: No, not because it has too many connections but because it's already connected to two nodes which have only two connections and this would've made it too easy to solve this situation.

The solution would be like this if we took the other way around:

We go to E and check each connection. Since E has two nodes that each have two connections connected to it, E is connected to two outer nodes. Two outer nodes will mean that this is also an outer node (because of how you set your nodes up), then we remove all other connections of E and we're just left with the B-F connection. We iterate to F and remove B-F, then iterate through the rest and we're done. (This would've made the example somewhat meaningless).

So, there you have it. I don't have any code to show for it, but it should be relatively easy (since you already seem to have experience) to turn the logic into a code algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! This is great! I was thinking about deleting the edges that are shared between triangles, but for that, I needed to adjust my code so it stores triangles too. I am definitely going to try this first.

Comment: Hi again. Sadly, this solution didn't work for me. I dont know if it was because I didn't understand this method completely or because it just works  with some shapes.

In my mesh, I had a section that caused problems to this method because of the angle. I ended up doing it like I commented before and it works!.